# Flask server events working in development but not in production

Tags: python, python-3.x, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have a flask route that should generate server events to the browser. Basically what the function do is:
 1. load a csv file
 2. for each line of the csv file
 3. save username and email in sql database (using sqlalchemy)
 4. update counter (for progress status)
 5. send event to the browser

The thing is that the function works well when I'm in development mode (using flask built-in server) but in production mode (using NginX and gunicorn) the function stops after a few seconds, so as the counter never reach 100, it result in browser calling the function again, and this loop never ends because the event never get the close statement. So the main question is, why it works in development and not in production?
Here is mi code:

```
# Update or construct database if a csv file was submitted
@app.route("/constructDatabase/<string:filename>", methods=["GET","POST"])
def constructDatabase(filename):
    # context manager to open csv file
    csvFile = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), newline='')
    # get lines count of csv file
    totalLines = len(csvFile.readlines())
    # reset reader pointer
    csvFile.seek(0)
    # current percent status
    current_status = 0
    def generate(file, counter):
        # unpack and iterate over the csv file to get all the names and emails
    for Company,Address,City,State,Zip,County,Phone,Website,Contact,Title,Direct_Phone,Email,Sales,Employees,SIC_Code,Industry in csv.reader(file, delimiter=','):
        yield ':keep connection alive\n\n'
        counter += 1
        # if a user has not contact name or email then not useful
        if Email == None or Email == '':
            yield f'id: {counter}\nevent: message\ndata: {round(counter / totalLines * 100, 1)}\n\n'
            continue
        if Contact == None or Contact == '':
            yield f'id: {counter}\nevent: message\ndata: {round(counter / totalLines * 100, 1)}\n\n'
            continue
        # Create user as instance of User class
        user = Users(company=Company, address=Address, city=City, state=State, 
        zip=Zip, country=County, phone=Phone, website=Website, contact=Contact, 
        title=Title, direct_phone = Direct_Phone, email=Email, sales=Sales, 
        employees=Employees, sic_code=SIC_Code, industry=Industry)
        # Add user to database
        db.session.add(user)
        # get current percent status of building database
        yield f'id: {counter}\nevent: message\ndata: {round(counter / totalLines * 100, 1)}\n\n'
    # Save changes in database
    db.session.commit()
    print("SAVING DATABASE .......")
    # close file
    file.close()
return Response(generate(csvFile, current_status), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

Java script code now:
    `javascript`

```
// create Event source connection with the server to listen for incoming msg
var source = new EventSource(`/constructDatabase/${filename}`);
// if new msg was received
source.onmessage = function(msg) {
// update progress bar
$('.progress-bar').css('width', msg.data+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', msg.data);  
// if is 100 percent close connection to the server
if (msg.data == 100) {
    source.close();
    // Hide label
    $('.prog-bar-label').addClass('d-none');
    // Hide CSV progress bar
    $('.csvProgressBar').addClass('d-none');
    // reset progress bar
    $('.csvProgressBar').find('.progress-bar').css('width', 0+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', 0);
           } 
     };
     source.onerror = function(error){
           console.log(error.data);
     };
```

Comment: Check the nginx and gunicorn logs to see which one may be shutting down request and return with results.

Comment: I have this error everytime connection is reset:  `[error] 14186#14186: *13628 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out what's going on here. The thing is that the flask developer server, when it runs, he doesn't have any timeout declared, so a function can be waiting a response for a long while. But in production server with gunicorn, it has a default timeout very short, so if a function takes long to get a response back and the timeout time is reached, gunicorn kill the process and exit the function, so the streaming process at the browser side, thinks that was and error in the server, when was just really a delayed func. The solution is to increase the timeout in gunicorn with --timeout (desired timeout value here) and will be good. Don't use very big timeout values, just try to figure out how long it takes to your function to get a response back and use that value. Remember this value will be now the same for all your functions.